Retrieving a Hebrew folder path using VBA 7.1
I get wrong characters and "???" instead of Hebrew when trying to retrieve a folder path using VBA (by user browse selection) then plot it with question marks.
I changed the locale. Is there any command to convert to UTF-8?
This is from a recorded macro from SOLIDWORKS that does a SaveAs on the open file in a Hebrew folder path (happening also in Excel and every other app):
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part as Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Save As

    longstatus = Part.SaveAs3("\\domain\users_profiles$\lila\Desktop\??? ????\models\FH-02-003.SLDASM", 0, 0)

End Sub


Can you please show the code to retrieve the folder?

hi, just edited my question

@lila it's because of OS localization, try to change system locale, go to  Control Panel=>Region=>Administrative=>Change system local... select Hebrew and restart you machine.

Guido's StringTools library (single module) has UTF-8 conversion and more. A must-have in VBA. It also handles all locales and is cross-platform/Mac-compatible.
